# Svelte FilePond Image Preview only working on old uploads

Tags: javascript, svelte, filepond

I have an old project that I'm currently working on updating to a new version of Svelte, and have loaded up my old svelte-filepond component that all appears to work fine, apart from previewing recent images.

If I load up an old image to edit, it will preview the image fine... if I load up a new image to edit, it will not preview the image at all.

Both the old image and the new image comes from an AWS S3 Storage, Both Images load fine and have full access to get/put/update/delete. Both images require server={} configuration to preload into filepond using filepond's load: as follows.

```
load: (source, load) => {
  const myRequest = new Request(source);
  fetch(myRequest).then(response => {
    response.blob()
    .then(myBlob => {
      load(myBlob)}
    );
 });
},
```

I have console logged out every single part of my filepond system from the moment the files enter the component until the filepond component is live and displaying the filename, filesize.

I end up with a perfect blob in both filepond components at the end, but one is displaying an image, and the other one is not. The only difference between the two images is that one is old, uploaded last year, and the other is new, uploaded recently.

[Old Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzP1m.png)
[New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq4Ms.png)

Does anyone know What could possible cause this kind of situation?

Comment: I have solved this.

It appears as though my S3 Uploader was ignoring mime types and uploading everything new as an application/octet-stream, stuffing up filepond.

Comment: Either delete the question if you think it is unhelpful to others or post an answer yourself and accept it as soon as you are allowed to.